# Anaconda tkinter menus. where do I put the call and the code?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, anaconda, tk-toolkit

Running Anaconda because I want the stats features. So I have created the menu system but I'm not sure:

- once I click on (for example) the Group t option, I want to present
  the user with more options with other drop downs or data entry etc.

But I don't know where to put the code for that statistic and then how do I call it.

In the C++ world it could be in a separate file or later on in the program with a call function. I don't know how to do this in Anaconda.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.main_window()
        self.widgets()

    # All main window parameters go here
    def main_window(self):
        self.master.title("Quick-Stat")
        self.master.geometry("1000x800")
        self.pack()

    def widgets(self):
        main_menu = tk.Menu(self.master, tearoff=0)
        self.master.config(menu=main_menu)

        # Create File Menu and Drop Down
        file = tk.Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        file.add_command(label="Save")
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        # Create Edit Menu and Drop Down
        edit = tk.Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        edit.add_command(label="Undo")
        main_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)

        #Create Means Analysis Menu and Drop Down
        means = tk.Menu(main_menu,tearoff=0)
        means.add_command(label="Group t")
        means.add_command(label="Paired t")
        means.add_separator()
        means.add_command(label="ANOVA")
        means.add_separator()
        means.add_command(label="Mann-Whitney U")
        means.add_command(label="Wilcoxon rank sum")
        main_menu.add_cascade(label="Means", menu=means)

        #Create Chi-square Analysis Menus and Drop Down
        chi = tk.Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        chi.add_command(label="Chi-Square 2x2 table")
        chi.add_command(label="Chi-Square for larger table")
        chi.add_separator()
        chi.add_command(label="McNemar's Test")
        chi.add_command(label="Fisher's Exact")
        main_menu.add_cascade(label="Tables", menu=chi)

        #Create Help Menu
        help = tk.Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        help.add_command(label="Means Analysis")
        help.add_command(label="Chi-Square Analysis")
        main_menu.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=help)


main = tk.Tk()
comm_prog = Window(master=main)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for improving your question.

Comment: Do you mean like submenu example in [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/menustoolbars/)?

Comment: it is small program so put all in one file. If you really need it in separated file then put in file ie. `options.py` and do `import options` and then you can use `options.option1`, `options.option2`, etc.

Comment: I am having a hard time asking the question... so when a user would click on 'Group t' then what? do I put a statement in after that where I start to ask the user questions and process the data? Or is there a call to a different area of the program? Lets say I wanted to ask the user next.. "What is the sample size?" How and where would I put that so that I can start to process the data? And where do I put that code?

Comment: Are you talking about doing cascaded submenus or opening up a new window (probably a custom dialog window)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean you want to open a new custom dialog, what you do is you create a callback method on your `Window` class that creates a new `tk.Toplevel` instance (or a subclass of it if you prefer). FWIW, the `main` window object you got from calling `tk.Tk()` is actually an instance of a subclass of that class.

```
    def group_t_callback(self):
        dialog = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        dialog.title("The Title")
        dialog.transient(self.master)
        # You might want to put some contents in here, etc.
```

Then, once you have that method, you can just plumb it into the menu entry when you create it:

```
        means.add_command(label="Group t...", command=self.group_t_callback)
        # Hint: also check out the accelerator kwarg...
```

A convention you should be aware of is that users tend to expect menu items that open dialogs to have `...` at the end of their label. Not all applications are entirely consistent about it, but it is a good convention to follow if you can.

---

For more about making dialogs, try the [Introduction to Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) online book. There's a *lot* of details that I've omitted.